# Bluetooth keyboard and mouse problem

Tags: bluetooth

I am brand new to Ubuntu - NEVER used it before.

I have created a DVD to run Ubuntu from but when I select boot (Ubuntu) from CD on my Win XP machine the mouse and keyboard do not work once Ubuntu starts.

I have tried using the locate buttons to no avail.

Comment: You have a bluetooth mouse and keyboard?  We can't help if we don't know what mouse and keyboard you have....  Is this a mac?

Comment: @Seth - `Win XP machine`. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My PC is a Dell Optiplex 745 (running Win XP Pro - if it makes a diff). The keyboard/mouse/bluetooth dongle are also all Dell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the devices. Start by dis-connecting the blue tooth USB's. Plug in a **wired** keyboard + Mouse and then plug in the Bluetooth USB's/ Whatever you plug in to make it work. Ubuntu will search for what they are and connect them.

If this is a DVD and Ubuntu is not installed to the actual HDD, Ubuntu will not remember these settings, meaning that you will have to do this every time you boot.

To keep these settings, install Ubuntu.

Hope this helps!!!

**Edit**: Maybe you could boot with those USB's off, and then plug them in when Ubuntu is loaded! Try it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was hoping there was some config file that could be added to my boot up DVD / I don't have any cabled mouse or keyboard kit at home anymore. I can probably get some from work but I really wanted to play today. :-) Oh well, they say patience is a virtue!

Comment: Wait a min. See edit.

Comment: I tried booting without the dongle. I get a message about bluetooth wanting to access the service AND accept Y/N but I can't say "yes". It'll have to wait until after I go to work and borrow some wired bits.